# Simulator_gazebo (1.5) and ROS groovy

Tags: gazebo, gazebo-model, gazebo-1.5, groovy

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I'm trying out [simulator_gazebo](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/simulator_gazebo) with groovy.
I noticed that when I tried to add a turtlebot to a test world that there were errors and warnings (see below). But it seems to be working.

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<sdf version="1.3">
  <world name="default">
    <physics type="ode">
      <gravity>0 0 0</gravity>
      <ode>
        <solver>
          <type>quick</type>
          <dt>0.001</dt>
          <iters>40</iters>
          <sor>1.0</sor>
        </solver>
        <constraints>
          <cfm>0.0</cfm>
          <erp>0.2</erp>
          <contact_max_correcting_vel>100.0</contact_max_correcting_vel>
          <contact_surface_layer>0.0</contact_surface_layer>
        </constraints>
      </ode>
    </physics>
    <!-- A global light source -->
    <include>
      <uri>model://sun</uri>
    </include>
    <!-- A ground plane -->
    <include>
      <uri>model://ground_plane</uri>
    </include>
    <include>
      <uri>model://turtlebot</uri>
      <pose>0 0 1 0 0 0</pose>
    </include>
  </world>
</sdf>
```

Response observed is:

```
Gazebo multi-robot simulator, version 1.5.0
Copyright (C) 2013 Open Source Robotics Foundation.
Released under the Apache 2 License.
http://gazebosim.org

Msg Waiting for master
[ INFO] [1366299708.959245033]: waitForService: Service [/gazebo/set_physics_properties] has not been advertised, waiting...
Msg Connected to gazebo master @ http://127.0.0.1:11345
Msg Publicized address: XX.YY.XX.YY
Warning [ODEPhysics.cc:201] Gravity vector is (0, 0, 0). Objects will float.
[ INFO] [1366299709.183638696]: waitForService: Service [/gazebo/set_physics_properties] is now available.
Error [Events.hh:141] Events::ConnectWorldUpdateStart is deprecated in v 1.5.0. Please use Events::ConnectWorldUpdateBegin
Error [Events.hh:141] Events::ConnectWorldUpdateStart is deprecated in v 1.5.0. Please use Events::ConnectWorldUpdateBegin
Error [Events.hh:141] Events::ConnectWorldUpdateStart is deprecated in v 1.5.0. Please use Events::ConnectWorldUpdateBegin
[ INFO] [1366299709.276198138]: Starting to spin physics dynamic reconfigure node...
Warning [Publisher.cc:130] Queue limit reached for topic /gazebo/default/pose/info, deleting message (only this warning is printed to the console, see the ~/.gazebo/gzserver.log and ~/.gazebo/gzclient.log files for future warnings).
Warning [Publisher.cc:130] Queue limit reached for topic /gazebo/default/diagnostics, deleting message (only this warning is printed to the console, see the ~/.gazebo/gzserver.log and ~/.gazebo/gzclient.log files for future warnings).
Warning [Publisher.cc:130] Queue limit reached for topic /gazebo/default/physics/contacts, deleting message (only this warning is printed to the console, see the ~/.gazebo/gzserver.log and ~/.gazebo/gzclient.log files for future warnings).
```

Changing the turtlebot to a create, these warnings do not appear. But adding a kinect or a camera to the create also causes 1 queue limit message to be shown.

What else should be tested?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/2462/simulator_gazebo-(1.5)-and-ros-groovy/) by [SL Remy](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/43/sl-remy/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 319 on 2013-04-18

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dejanpan](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/30/dejanpan/) on 2013-04-20**:
The errors are not critical, just means that certain functions (e.g. ConnectWorldUpdateStart) were deprecated but still kept in for back compatibility.

**Comment by [carolineQ](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/361/carolineq/) on 2013-05-24**:
Hi ! Are you using a URDF model for the Turtlebot or a SDF one ? Is it the Turtlebot 1 or 2 you have ? I am working with groovy and I didn't manage to have the Turtlebot 2 model loaded in Gazebo. Thanks for help.

**Comment by [SL Remy](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/43/sl-remy/) on 2013-05-25**:
This is an SDF model downloaded from the database. I think the robot looks like a Turtlebot 1 (but I honestly didn't look too closely, I was more interested in the data coming from the device)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Answer in comments.

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2013-09-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0